# what is the point of define differential equation on strips?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on the strip
>   $$S:|x|\leq a,|y|<\infty,(a>0),$$
>   and let $I$ denote the interval $|x|\leq a$. Suppose $\phi$ is a real-valued function on $I$ satisfying
>   $$y''+\lambda^2y=f(x,y),y(0)=0,y'(0)=1,(\lambda>0).$$

This is the state of a problem and I have a question about it, if $\phi$ is a solution of this then $\phi$ must be continuous on $I$ so it has to be bounded (say $|\phi|=|y|\leq M$), then what is the point of define differential equation on strips?

Comment: how it could not be bounded, if it is differentiable, which implies continuous in a compact set, it must be bounded

Comment: It isn't necessarily saying that your solution has to be in the strip, just that is where $f$ is defined. This is probably for some setup to a uniqueness and existence theorem, to make sure that you actually have a solution in the given interval.